# Why is my simple pthreads program crashing with a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>//getch();
#include <termios.h>//getch();
#include <pthread.h>
volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;

char getch()
{
  int buf=0;
  struct termios old= {0};
  fflush(stdout);
  if(tcgetattr(0, &old)<0)
    perror("tcsetattr()");
  old.c_lflag&=~ICANON;
  old.c_lflag&=~ECHO;
  old.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
  old.c_cc[VTIME]=0;
  if(tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old)<0)
    perror("tcsetattr ICANON");
  if(read(0,&buf,1)<0)
    perror("read()");
  old.c_lflag|=ICANON;
  old.c_lflag|=ECHO;
  if(tcsetattr(0, TCSADRAIN, &old)<0)
    perror ("tcsetattr ~ICANON");
  //printf("%c\n",buf);//to print the value typed.
  return buf;
}

void *send_function()
{
  printf("\n Send Thread \n");
  //return 0;
}

void my_function(int sig)
{ // can be called asynchronously
  flag = 1; // set flag
}

int main ()
{
  char selection;//user input(s or r)
  pthread_t send;
  while(1)
  {  
    signal(SIGINT, my_function);
    //printf("\n Before SIGINT \n");            
    if(flag)
    { 
        printf("\n Choose your terminal S or R \n");
        selection=getch();
        flag = 0;
    }   
    if(selection=='s')
        if(pthread_create(&send,NULL,send_function(),NULL))
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
        }
    else if(selection=='r')
        printf("Receive Function is received");
    //printf("\n After SIGINT \n"); 
 }
  return 0;  

}
```

Output:

```
 nivas@balakrishnan-HCL-Desktop:~/C_sample$ gcc -pthread -o thread thread.c

 nivas@balakrishnan-HCL-Desktop:~/C_sample$ ./thread

 Choose your terminal S or R

 Send Thread

 Send Thread

 Send Thread

 Send Thread

 Send Thread
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
 nivas@balakrishnan-HCL-Desktop:~/C_sample$ ^C
 nivas@balakrishnan-HCL-Desktop:~/C_sample$
```

In the above program I'm getting a segmentation fault. My required output is to print `"Send Thread"` continuosly once I press `'s'`. I have looked into previous similar questions, but I can't find answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the function `send_function()`. [According to the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create), this function should take a pointer to `void` as an argument, and should return a pointer to void:

```
void * send_function(void *parg)
{
  printf("\n Send Thread \n");
  return parg;
}
```

You also need to correct your function call, which includes a pair of stray parenthesis:

```
if(pthread_create(&send,NULL,send_function,NULL)) {}
```

As it is, your program will loop printing `"Send Thread"` until your system runs out of resources. You can create detached threads that release system resources when they terminate by adding these lines before the loop in `main()`:

```
pthread_attr_t attr;

if (pthread_attr_init(&attr) != 0) {
    perror("Error in pthread_attr_init()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED) != 0) {
    perror("Error in pthread_attr_setdetachstate()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
}
```

Then change the `pthread_create()` call inside the loop to:

```
if(pthread_create(&send, &attr, send_function, NULL)) {}
```

After this change your program should print `"Send Thread"` repeatedly, releasing resources after each message is printed, until you stop it.

Comment: that was the correct one @david.now it is working good.there is no segmentation problem.

Comment: after making changes in the code .after I press key 's' it is not working infinitly throughout the program.it stops after few cycle.I don't know why it is happenig like this .

Comment: @NivasB-- you probably want to create detached threads here. I added a bit about this to my answer.

Comment: Bowing yeah I will make use of it

Answer (score 1):

Is this line:

```
if(pthread_create(&send,NULL,send_function(),NULL))
```

A typo?   The third argument to `pthread_create` is a function pointer, where the thread should start.

It should read:

```
if(pthread_create(&send,NULL,send_function,NULL))
```

Also, the threads you create won’t really exit unless you set their attribute bits to detached, or explicitly detach them, or collect the status with `pthread_join`.

Comment: Also, the `send_function()` claims to return a `void*`, but returns nothing.